# CSS - Dashed or dotted text-shadow

Tags: css, text

I want to create a CSS effect with text-shadow to get dashed or dotted border around text. Like this:
[image]
or this:
[image]
Is it possible to do that with CSS3 or/and JavaScript?

Comment: I think there will no way to achieve this, but you can do a bit similar using `box-shadow` and `-webkit-text-stroke`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to use this what you say in your answer. Can you insert a demo or describe how to use it into your answer?

Comment: @Kaprog Will you create another question for gradient shadow?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with CSS yet.  You can try with using `<canvas>` or look for web fonts

Answer (score 0):

As per above comment, Find that `text-shadow` and `text-stroke` here:

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #000;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 #ff0000, 0 1px #ff0000, 1px 0 #ff0000, 0 -1px #ff0000;
}

h2, h3{    
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin: 30px 0 0;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 0 #000, -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
}
h3{
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Text Shadow</h1>
<h2>Text Stroke</h2>
<h3>Text Stroke</h3>
```

For more you can also refer this https://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/

Comment: Those are the only options you have. Since your border styles are overlapping the text itself it is not possible to create it with `text-shadow` / `box-shadow`. You could use `text-stroke` like in the example but it only supports solid strokes.